# TensorFlow Output: One-Hot Encoding vs. Index

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning

I want to ask a conceptual question about when to use one-hot encoding and when to use index to represent the labels in multi-class classification problems in tensorflow. I encountered the dimension problems about these, because I am not sure when to use which.

For example, in this fully connected NN example, one-hot encoding is proper. (https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/examples/3_NeuralNetworks/neural_network_raw.py)
But in this CNN example, index is proper. (https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/examples/3_NeuralNetworks/convolutional_network.py).

When I used one-hot encoding for the labels in the CNN example code, I got the error: "ValueError: Rank mismatch: Rank of labels (received 2) should equal rank of logits minus 1 (received 2)". But when I used index for labels, no problem.

Could someone explain when to use one-hot encoding and when to use index in tensorflow?

Comment: Both examples use one-hot encoding (you get one probability value per class in the output), but one uses [`tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits) and the other uses [`tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits). The second allows you to give indices as input, but it does the same thing. For multi-class classification, you will most likely want one-hot encoding (one output per class), either directly or indirectly.

Comment: (btw [`tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits) is now deprecated and should be replaced by [`tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2)... although you probably find simpler to use [`tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits))

Comment: For the second example, I tried to follow their code, but one-hot encoding would produce "ValueError: Rank mismatch: Rank of labels (received 2) should equal rank of logits minus 1 (received 2)" error. But when I changed it to index, it worked.

Comment: The CNN example from Tensorflow website (https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/estimators/cnn) also uses index encoding for labels. So I am not sure when to use which.